# Google storage get image serving url from outside Appengine

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to get the serving url of an image on Google storage. I'm using the relatively straightforward code below

```
ImagesService svc = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();
String bucketId;
String fileName;
String url = svc.getServingUrl(String.format("/gs/%s/%s", bucketId, fileName));
```

However, I'm trying to run this code outside of appengine (for example, locally or on Digital Ocean). I've just slapped this dependency in Maven to get the Google api

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
<artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
<version>1.9.48</version>
</dependency>
```

but I haven't been able to find any information on where to put a config file for authorization, and I'm fairly confident that I need more than just that Maven dependency.

I'm also beginning to suspect that it's not even possible to use `com.google.appengine.api.*` dependencies when not running on app-engine in the cloud.